# Java class file format and the constant pool

Tags: java, class, jvm

im a little confused with the tag values of the constant pool in java class files as described [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html).
it seems at the end of the cp table theres a "0x0031" which is neither a valid cp entry nor the following access flag:

> Hexdump:
>
> 00008a4: 2e6a 6176 6100 3100 0100 0300
> 0000 0000  .java.1.........

the last entry of the constant pool that i can read properly ends at "2e6a 6176 61" (.java) the "00 01" part should be the accessflag (public) following the constant pool table, but before that there's those "0x0031" valued bytes which i dont know how to interpret. Is this just an invalid cp table entry that i have to ignore, or am i missing something from the specs?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you compare your implementation against a working reference like ObjectWeb's ASM. I would look to see what it makes of the data.

Comment: An access flag of 0x01 (ACC_SUPER) is also suspect since usually this flag is combined with 0x20 (ACC_SUPER). Have you tried using `javap -verbose` on this class?

Comment: @jörn: you're absolutely right, i didn't realize those were bitmasks. Thanks!. the zero tag value was just indicating an invalid cp entry.

Comment: So the 0x31 are the acces flags, meaning a public final class?

Comment: @Jörn: exactly, i got 0x31 on my public final class which is 0x01 for ACC_PUBLIC 0x10 for ACC_FINAL and 0x20 for ACC_SUPER